# locals() function doesn't give results in list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, local-variables

Inside a script I have conditions to created variables with names of files. At the end of the script I want to know which variables were created. I use `in locals()` function to check it. If I do if with a simple list building it works fine, but with list comprehension I don't get the results. Why?

To be clear, I don't need suggestions to bypass the problem (I can just use the simple list building), just an explanation to the behaviour.

In my example `file_08` and `file_14` variables were created, but `file_15` wasn't.

```
all_files = []
for file in ['file_08', 'file_14', 'file_15']:
    if file in locals():
        all_files.append(file)
print(all_files)
['file_08', 'file_14']
```

Works, but:

```
print([file for file in ['file_08', 'file_14', 'file_15'] if file in locals()])
[]
```

Doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The locals() function returns a dictionary containing the variables defined in the local namespace. Unless you have defined variables with the names 'file_88', 'file_14', and 'file_15' within the executable name space, you will get an empty list.  You can verify this by printing the contents of locals() and see what you get back.

Comment: To expand on this, comprehensions create their own namespace (this didn't always used to be the case in older versions), so the local namespace will be fairly barren. `globals` will have much more of what you're looking for.

Comment: @Aaron answer is the right one. This is not the answer itprorh66 wrote, as he suggested to print `locals()`, and it is not possible to print inside list comprehension.